# Conformality of Annuli's and ratio of their radii

Tags: complex-analysis

Show 2 Annuli are conformally equivalent to each other if and only if the ratio of the radii are equal.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Well, for starters, certainly you should be able to do the easy direction.

Comment: @TedShifrin that would be showing if the ratio of the radii are equal then 2 annuli are conformally equivalent, that one is straight forward. the other direction however is the one which im not getting.

Comment: OK. Good. The other direction is quite challenging. Presumably you have some guidance on how to approach it, given what you've done in class. I will also comment that you should search this site before posting questions, as this has appeared in numerous questions before.

Comment: @TedShifrin what i think is to somehow use harmonic functions? and I will search on the site

Comment: See G. M. Goluzin "Geometric Theory of Functions of a Complex Variable", Chapter V.1.

Answer (score 0):

http://cykenleung.blogspot.de/2012/04/conformal-equivalence-of-annuli.html

here is a proof for both directions